# Clear all property values in a properties file

Tags: shell, properties

I have a properties file which contains several name=value pairs. This properties file contains several secrets in value. My requirement is to delete the property value after reading the values using a shell script. The property file will also contain comments.

Properties file:

```
#docker image key
name=secret_value

#username
abc=bcd

#password
def=efg
```

The shell script should delete all values after reading the properties file like:

New Properties file :

```
#docker image key
name=
#username
abc=
#password
def=
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried already?  Do you have the start of a script we can look at?

Answer (score 0):

In the script, after the properties file is read, add the below command:
sed -i 's/\=.*/=/' property_file_name

Comment: @MalarKandasamy Please accept and upvote the answer if you found it useful. Thanks

Comment: I did that already. Since my reputation is less than 15, it won't be displayed.